# Pasting is not working with Nav Controller/Navigation UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, clipboard

I've been trying to create an auto-paste feature in my downloader app. My app has an editText and when a user opens the app the app will automatically check for a copied link that matches certain parameters. The main page has two fragments, one of them has this feature.

Problem is when I use `bottomNavigationView` with `NavController` using `Navigation UI`, that feature doesn't work. It shows null as a result when checking for clipboard data.

But when I use an `adapter` extending `FragmentStateAdapter` instead of `navigation UI` then it works properly.

```
 if (!this.clipboardManager.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                    Log.d("ContentValues", "PasteText");
                } else if (this.clipboardManager.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    ClipData.Item itemAt = this.clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
                    if (itemAt.getText().toString().contains(TikTok)) {
                        inputLink.setText(itemAt.getText().toString());
                        resetButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pasteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        if (Util.getAuto(requireContext())) {
                            String string = inputLink.getText().toString();
                            getDownloadLink(string);
                            Util.showProgress(requireContext());
                        }

                    }
                } else if (this.clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString().contains(TikTok)) {
                    inputLink.setText(this.clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString());
                    resetButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pasteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (Util.getAuto(requireContext())) {
                        String string = inputLink.getText().toString();
                        getDownloadLink(string);
                        Util.showProgress(requireContext());
                    }

                }
```

I don't know what is the issue here. It works in fragment when I use Adapter but not with Navigation UI. Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue. I thought it is something with my code. Later I switched to an adapter.

Comment: Do you find any solution or any clues about that?